# Implement df.groupby('user')['item'].apply(np.array) in cuDF

Tags: python, pandas, cudf

Is there any way to replicate this simple pandas functionality to cuDF?

Note that array lengths are varying.

An example of the expected output using pandas and NumPy(CuPy in the  cuDF case) be found below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':[0,1,0,2,1], 'item':[1,2,3,4,5]})
res = df.groupby('user')['item'].apply(np.array)
res
# Output:
# user
# 0    [1, 3]
# 1    [2, 5]
# 2       [4]
# Name: item, dtype: object
```

Comment: cuDF does not yet support the nested data structures necessary for things like lists inside rows of a column, though this is in the roadmap. It's possible you can get your final output using cuDF in a different way. If you'd like more assistance, please provide a reproducible example of your input and final desired output.

Comment: Thanks. cuDF doesn't currently support this kind of column. Presumably you want to created this ragged column to ultimately do *something* downstream that you care about. If you update your question to include that "something", it's possible you can still achieve that ultimate output with cuDF.

Comment: I am building a recommender system trained on implicit feedback. I basically need the interactions of each user so that I can uniformly sample random "negative" interactions for each user at the beginning of each training epoch. The item ids are generated so that they have values between `0, len(df.item.unique())`. So, having the interactions I can sample from the set difference `set(len(df.item.unique())) - set(res.loc[user])`.